# Git merging one branch into another is a two way merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, meld

My git repo looks like this:

```
         _ branch_a
        /
master /
        \_ branch_b
```

Now I want to merge branch_b into branch_a, **not** either branch into master.

So, I did

```
git checkout branch_a
git merge branch_b
```

And git went and found a couple of conflicts.

When I do `git mergetool` using `meld` what I get on the console is

```
 {local}: modified file
 {remote}: modified file
```

and a window showing only LOCAL and REMOTE.

What I want to know is:

1. Why isn't the shared base of what was in master shown?
2. Between LOCAL and REMOTE, which one am I supposed to edit?

Comment: If you want to merge A into B the correct commands are `git checkout branch_b
git merge branch_a`

Comment: What version of git are you using?  When I use meld as a mergetool it presents it as a three-way merge off of the common base.  I have never seen it show just two files, so I have no idea which you're expected to modify.

Comment: Strange, that version should definitely be giving meld the common base version of the file along with the versions from the two branches.

Answer (score 11):

If you merge a branch A into a branch B the conflicts that you get come from the difference between both branches and not from the difference with master. executing `git diff` in A or B will give you however the diff with mastere since it is the ancestor

Normally the **local** branch should be the one you are **merging into** and the **remote** the one you want to **merge**. Anyway in your computer you will only have one copy of the file so just modify it

Comment: It's technically true that the `master` branch wouldn't be involved in that merge. But, the commit that master points to in that case would be since it is the common ancestor.

Comment: The diff of a branch (a or b) is taken from the comparisson with the ancestor (master in this case) that is true, but when you merge A into B the conflicts are given by those branches and not by master. That is what I meant. I edited my answer